# Extracting multiple values from the same column, X, given their shared value in column Y

Tags: sql, postgresql

Before everything, I would like to say thanks for your help! I am currently working on data provided by UK rail; the data I have is currently contained in a relational database on PostgreSQL. My ultimate goal is to extract origin-destination pairs that are served by the railway network.

Right now, entries are stored in rows that each contain one stop/location in a train's journey. For instance, if a train travels from D to G via E and F, then D will be contained in a row and marked as an origin_location, E and F as an intermediate_location and G as a terminating_location. Each of them will also be marked with additional details such as train ID, time of the departure/passage/arrival and date of travel.

Eventually, from these entries I hope to write a query that gives me all possible origin-destination pairs. So for instance, continuing the example above, I would like the query to produce a table that gives me rows as such: D-E; D-F; D-G; E-F; E-G; F-G. The linkages between these locations are based on them sharing a common train identifier that is in another column, "Column Y".

I am at the very start of my research, but I don't expect you to help me find a specific code as a solution. Rather, I just hope you could point me in the direction as to which functions I could read up into using, and we'll see where it goes from there.

Someone has tried to work with the same dataset, albeit building this function with a slightly different purpose - that is, to get the full timetable of all trains running on a particular day (with each train departure/intermediate/terminating location as a row). The function is detailed here: https://github.com/jhumphry/ukraildata_etl/blob/master/sql/mca_get_full_timetable.sql

Comment: (1) Sample data and desired results are more helpful than paragraphs of explanation.  (2) What you want are recursive CTEs.  You should probably ask a new, ore specific question on how to apply them.

Comment: Thanks Gordon - I will try and look into what you suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=77ca5954d9c0966d34b312178ceed84e)

You need a self-join on an ordered stop id (hope you have such a column). You have to join every journey with itself but only with the following stops:

```
SELECT
    s1.journey_id,
    s1.stop_name,
    s2.stop_name
FROM
    schedule s1
JOIN schedule s2 ON s1.journey_id = s2.journey_id AND s1.stop_id < s2.stop_id
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it!

Comment: Just realised that that was a link you posted there. I've looked and that helps a lot. Thanks for the trouble!